# Merge default array from function argument

Tags: php

I believe this is a long shot, but consider the following:

```
public function options(array $options = ['route' => '', 'placeholder' => '']) {}
```

Could I invoke this method such as:

```
options(['route' => 'search'])
```

And maintain placeholder as `'placeholder' => ''`

Is there anything that could merge the original `$options` array with the new one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could maintain an array of default options and then merge them with the supplied function parameters.

```
function options(array $options = []) 
{
    $defaults = ['route' => '', 'placeholder' => ''];
    $options = array_merge($defaults, $options);
    // ...
}

options(['route' => 'search']);
```

Now, all the following would work:

```
options(['route' => 'search']);
options(['route' => 'search', 'placeholder' => 1]);
options();
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["route"]=>
  string(6) "search"
  ["placeholder"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

array(2) {
  ["route"]=>
  string(6) "search"
  ["placeholder"]=>
  int(1)
}

array(2) {
  ["route"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["placeholder"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Amal Murali is also correct, but, in the place of array_merge() one should consider using [array_merge_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) so that default options are not overwritten by the options passed when calling the function.

For example:

```
function getQuiz(array $options) {

  $default = array(
      'conditions' => array(
      'deleted' => 0
    )
  );

 $options = array_merge_recursive(
   $default, 
   $options
  );

  print_r($options);
}
```

and then calling it like:

```
$options = array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'id'=>1
  )
);

getQuiz( $options );
```

Doing a print_r( $options ) inside getQuiz() would give:

```
array(
  conditions' => array(
    'id' => '3',
    'deleted' => 1
  )
)
```

Comment: Important note here is this is meant for multidimensional arrays, no use for 1-dimensional arrays :)